# ArrayList compiler error

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, compiler-errors

I am trying to make an array list in Java in two spots, but I don't know what I am doing wrong. It says an array is required, but I don't know what that means because I am using an array list.

This is the line that's being messed up:

```
static char rSpaces(String problem, int count)
{
    num.add(problem.charAt(count));
    char no = num[count];
    return no;
}
```

If this helps, this is the line I created the array list in (I already imported it):

```
static ArrayList<Character> num = new ArrayList<Character>();
```

Answer (score 5):

`num[count]` is wrong, since `num` is not an array. Use `num.get(count)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

An `ArrayList` is not an array, so you can't use the array element `[]` syntax here.

With an `ArrayList`, use the [`get`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get%28int%29) method to access an element.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `ArrayList.get` to access the elements of an `ArrayList`. Change that to:

```
  char no = num.get(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Java `array` and `ArrayList` are different things.

You could access the size of the `ArrayList` by using method `size` as follows:

```
static char rSpaces(String problem, int count)
{
    num.add(problem.charAt(count));
    char no = num.get(count);
    return no;
}
```

---

If you want to access it as an array, you could "export" it using the `toArray` method as follows:

```
...
Character[] myArray = num.toArray(new Character[]{})
Character c = myArray[count];
...
```

Answer (score 0):

To access element of array use index operation using [] operator `num[count]` while in case of ArrayList you need to use `get(count)` method.